# Regex pattern validation in html failing

Tags: html

i want to write a validation on in html on a input type text , my requirement is that the string should start with a `/` followed by an alphanumeric input and then again a `/`

`Eg - /eric/pat123`

I have used the pattern tag and have written `pattern="[/].[A-Za-z]*"`

Please help me with the solution

Comment: \/[A-z0-9]+\/.+ ? Try here https://regexr.com

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried? It looks like you are not trying to validate `html` at all.

Comment: @PeterAbolins He is not trying to validate HTML. He is trying to perform input validation on an HTML form by using the pattern attribute.

Comment: @conyc Thanks, I was fully aware of that.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Why are you then asking for missing code? He has already provided the code that he tried: `pattern="[/].[A-Za-z]*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `^(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$` will match a string starting with `/` followed by any number of alphanumeric characters and then optionally repeating itself with another `/` and alphanumeric characters, repeating indefinitely.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19558019)

Comment: @Zooly Can you elaborate on why you believe that my answer does not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: It would be clearer if you provided a working example instead of saying "That could work"

Comment: @Zooly It was a working example. The author asked for a regex that would match a specific string. I provided that. I have however elaborated my answer with a detailed description of exactly what it matches.

Comment: @Conyc Thank you , it worked ! . i even tried **[/].[A-Za-z0-9/]***